# How to handle two possible date formats?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

My app calls a web api that sometimes returns json dates in this format:

```
"2017-01-18T10:49:00Z"
```

and sometimes in this format:

```
"2017-02-14T19:53:38.1173228Z"
```

I can use the following dateformat to convert the 2nd one to a Date object:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

But of course it doesn't work for the 1st one.

I've tried utilities like https://github.com/melvitax/DateHelper to see if it will work, but I haven't found a way to convert a json date (in any format) into a Date object.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Use two formatters. You can try both and get the first succesful result or check the length of the date string to choose one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try both formats:

```
let parser1 = DateFormatter()
parser1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

let parser2 = DateFormatter()
parser2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

func parse(_ dateString: String) -> Date? {
    let parsers = [parser1, parser2]

    for parser in parsers {
        if let result = parser.date(from: dateString) {
            return result
        }
    }

    return nil
}

print(parse("2017-01-18T10:49:00Z"))
print(parse("2017-02-14T19:53:38.1173228Z"))
```

Also note that the `Z` in the format is not a literal value.

Comment: I was hoping there was a solution to handle any date format. However, this works perfectly. Thanks